# Using .wrap() around several elements

Tags: jquery

I need to add another **div** around items with class **.item**

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="item">Item 1</div>
    <div class="item">Item 2</div>
    <div class="item">Item 3</div>
</div>



<div id="container">
  <div id="wrapper">
    <div class="item">Item 1</div>
    <div class="item">Item 2</div>
    <div class="item">Item 3</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I came across .wrap() but it wraps each .item in that div. How do I add just one for the group?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

jQuery has a [wrapAll](http://api.jquery.com/wrapAll/) function that will wrap the selected items.

```
$("#container div").wrapAll("<div id='wrapper'>");
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/zaAmN/

Comment: Wow, they thought of everything :)